# How to change model parameters in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a logistic regression model (`lr`) implemented in TensorFrlow. I use this model to generate predictions:

```
print s.run(preds, feed_dict = {x:X[:5]})
```

After that I try to change the model parameters in the following way:

```
lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, np.random.uniform(size=(inp_dim, out_dim)))
lr.b = tf.assign(lr.b, np.random.uniform(size=(out_dim,)))
s.run([lr.w, lr.b])
```

After that I generate new predictions in the same way:

```
print s.run(preds, feed_dict = {x:X[:5]})
```

Surprisingly, I get the same values as before the changes of the model parameters. So, it looks like I did not manage to change the model parameters.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**ADDED**

I probably need to provide more details about my "architecture". This is my implementation of the logistic regression:

```
class logreg:

    def __init__(self, inp_dim, out_dim, r = 1.0):
        # initialize values of model parameters
        w_val = np.random.uniform(-r, r, size = (inp_dim, out_dim))
        b_val = np.random.uniform(-r, r, size = (out_dim,))
        self.w = tf.Variable(w_val, tf.float64)
        self.b = tf.Variable(b_val, tf.float64)

    def get_model_graph(self, inp):
        return tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(inp, self.w) + self.b)
```

I use an instance of this class to define the prediction method:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, inp_dim])
preds = lr.get_model_graph(x)
```

I try to "redefine" the predict function by changing values of `lr.w` and `lr.b` and it does not work (as I have described above).

However, I found out that the new values of the model parameters become visible after I redefine the predict function:

```
lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, np.random.uniform(size=(inp_dim, out_dim)))
lr.b = tf.assign(lr.b, np.random.uniform(size=(out_dim,)))
s.run(lr.w)
s.run(lr.b)
preds = lr.get_model_graph(x)
```

Why is that? Isn't it the case that the computational graph for "preds" is bound ot `lr.w` and `lr.b` and to redefine the "preds" I just need to change the values of `w` and `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The described problematic behavior is caused by the fact that the first assignment of the values to the parameters of the model was done before the computational graph for the predictions has been defined.

In more detail, the following code will "block" the parameters of the model from any further re-assignment (so that it will be impossible to change the model parameters):

```
# instantiate the model
lr = logreg_tf(inp_dim = 4, out_dim = 3)

#  create the predict function
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, inp_dim])

# specify values of the parameters
w = np.array([
    [ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0],
    [ 4.0,  5.0,  6.0],
    [ 7.0,  8.0,  9.0],
    [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
    ])
b = np.array([13.0, 14.0, 15.0])

# set the values of the model parameters
lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, w)
lr.b = tf.assign(lr.b, b)

# initialize all the global variables
s = tf.Session()    
s.run([lr.w, lr.b])

preds = lr.get_model_graph(x)
```

In contrast, the following code prevents the "blocking":

```
# instantiate the model
lr = logreg_tf(inp_dim = 4, out_dim = 3)

#  create the predict function
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, inp_dim])
preds = lr.get_model_graph(x)

# specify values of the parameters
w = np.array([
    [ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0],
    [ 4.0,  5.0,  6.0],
    [ 7.0,  8.0,  9.0],
    [10.0, 11.0, 12.0]
    ])
b = np.array([13.0, 14.0, 15.0])

# set the values of the model parameters
lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, w)
lr.b = tf.assign(lr.b, b)

# initialize all the global variables
s = tf.Session()    
s.run([lr.w, lr.b])
```

The only difference between the two blocks of the code is the location of the line where "preds" is defined.

The described behavior is explained in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565367/is-it-allowed-to-assign-a-value-to-a-variable-before-it-enter-a-computational-gr).

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something weird when assigning the new values of your parameters.

Why don't you define a method of your class to reassign them:

```
def assign_parameters(self, param, new_val):
    self.param = tf.Variable(w_val, tf.float64)
```

Something like that cause I can't see the code updating the variables YOUR class is using when you execute `lr.get_model_graph(x)`

Comment: I try to update the variables that my class is using here: `lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, np.random.uniform(size=(inp_dim, out_dim)))
lr.b = tf.assign(lr.b, np.random.uniform(size=(out_dim,)))`

Comment: Instead of `lr.w = tf.assign(lr.w, w_val)` I tried to use `lr.w = tf.Variable(w_val, tf.float64)`. As a result I get an error message: ` Attempting to use uninitialized value`.