# Is it allowed to assign a value to a variable before it enter a computational graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I define a simple computational graph involving a variable. When I change a value of the variable it has an expected influence on the output of the computational graph (so, everything works fine, as expected):

```
s = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], tf.float32)

y = x + c

c = tf.assign(c, [3.0, 3.0, 3.0])   
s.run(c)
print 'Y1:', s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})

c = tf.assign(c, [2.0, 2.0, 2.0])
s.run(c)
print 'Y2:',  s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})
```

When I call this code I get:

```
Y1: [ 13.  23.  33.]
Y2: [ 12.  22.  32.]
```

So, the values after the `Y1` and `Y2` are different, as expected, because they are calculated with different values of `c`.

The problems start if I assign a value to the variable `c` before I define how it is involved into calculation of `y`. In this case I cannot assign a new value of `c`.

```
s = tf.Session()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], tf.float32)

c = tf.assign(c, [4.0, 4.0, 4.0])   # this is the line that causes problems
y = x + c

c = tf.assign(c, [3.0, 3.0, 3.0])   
s.run(c)
print 'Y1:', s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})

c = tf.assign(c, [2.0, 2.0, 2.0])
s.run(c)
print 'Y2:',  s.run(y, {x : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]})
```

As the output I get:

```
Y1: [ 14.  24.  34.]
Y2: [ 14.  24.  34.]
```

As you can see, each time I calculate `y`, I get results involving the old values of `c`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With TensorFlow, always keep in mind that you're building a [computation graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/basic_usage#the_computation_graph). In your first code snippet, you basically define `y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) + tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], tf.float32)`. In your second example, you define `y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) + tf.assign(tf.Variable([1.0, 1.0, 1.0], tf.float32), [4.0, 4.0, 4.0])`.

So, no matter which value you assign to *c*, the computation graph contains the *assign* operation and will always assign *[4.0, 4.0, 4.0]* to it before computing the sum.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because that you define the the add operation `y = x + c` right after `c = tf.assign(c, [4.0, 4.0, 4.0])`, so each time you run `y` out, `c = tf.assign(c, [4.0, 4.0, 4.0])` this op will always be excuted and although other assign operations will also be excuted but don't affect the final result.